# Apex Test Class Object Creation

Tags: apex

Could you please let me know If I am having a class called class1, which has 4 method called method1, method2, method3, method4.

When I am creating a test class for class1 called testclass1 with 4 test method called testmethod1, testmethod2, testmethod3, testmethod4.Should I be Instating class1 4 times in all  4 testmethod or I can instatiate once and reuse.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a class with four methods and you need to write a test class to test all four methods, you need to instantiate your class in each of the test methods, from what I have seen in best practices.

Keep in mind that you should be writing all use cases for each method, so your test class could have - and should have - at least an individual test and batch test for each method  and that each test method should test a use case both positive and negative. So one method could potentially generate five or more test methods in your test class.

You need to make sure at least 75% but strive for 100% of your class' code lines being tested by  your collective  test methods.

Answer (score 0):

> why you Creating four test methods, i think you can do it all in one
>   test method, like

```
public class1 {

public void method1(){} public void method2(){} public void method3(){} public void method4(){}  }
```

> and test class

```
static testMethod void testcostFree(){
class1 c= new class1();
c.method1();
c.method2();
c.method3();
c.method4();
}
}
```

Comment: I would think it would depend on the nature of the class and its context as to whether you want to test all four methods in one class or test each method individually so you can pinpoint if there is an issue.